# Auto-add (/overwrite) to Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Say I've got an Array `String[] str = new String[4]` and I can't add a String doing `str[n]=x`, is there a way, perhaps similar to ArrayList (`list.add(x)`), to simply add the new String?

Comment: Why can't you set with `str[n] = x`? There is no other way.

Comment: What is the value of n? and what is x?

Comment: what's the value of n and x?

Comment: you are wrong, try and see

Comment: n might be 0, 1, 2 or 3. x is a string, "bla bla bla" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only way is:

```
str[index] = "string here";
```

Also remember that `index` has to be valid, in other words, `index` has to be inside the range `[0, length - 1]`, where `length` is the length of the array `str`.